# Does the IQR or standard deviation change when scaling or shifting non-normal data?

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, standard-deviation

I'm aware that scaling or shifting data that is normal or almost perfectly normal will not significantly change the standard deviation. Through practice I've that this is not the case with non-normal data. Is there a way to normalize non-normal data that results in no or very little change in the standard deviation? For example, if you have a data set with zeros or negative values that shows no discernible distribution and it is shifted by adding 5 to each datum.

Comment: I can't fathom what "no discernible distribution" could be.

Comment: @gung I presumed it to be "I couldn't find a named distribution with that shape", but OP should clarify. Marc -- can you show any numerical examples where the distributional shape makes a difference to how (a) shifting and (b) scaling impact the standard deviation? (I ask because showing us might reveal a source of misconception that isn't presently dealt with in my answer.)

Answer (score 6):

**The premise in your opening sentence is wrong.**

While it's true that shifting (adding a constant) makes no difference to standard deviation, scaling certainly does. It doesn't matter what the distributional shape is! That makes no difference at all.

If you multiply observations by $c$, you multiply standard deviation by $c$  (assuming $c\geq 0$; more generally, you multiply standard deviation by $|c|$).

Also see Wikipedia on properties of [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Identities_and_mathematical_properties).

[In response to the edit of the question: The same comments apply to interquartile range. Again - shifting makes no difference, scaling (multiplying) by $c$ multiplies IQR by $|c|$, and distributional shape doesn't come into it.]

Comment: Glen I hope you don't mind my edit: the question screams your first sentence as a response.

Comment: Sorry, I should have confined my question to shifting. I thought my example would clue the reader in to my problem. I have two data sets. One contains zeros and the other contains negative values. The software program I'm using (ProUCL) will not run data if it contains zeros and I'm only concerned with right skewed data.

Comment: The program will run both sets of data if a constant is added to each datum. The is also specific for water quality data and runs formal tests to determine whether the data follows a normal, gamma, or lognormal distributions. If the data is neither of these three distributions the software returns output that there is no discernible distribution detected and, in specific situations will run non-parametric analysis to determine the standard deviation, and mean (as well as other parameters).

Comment: I understand that when adding a constant to a datum it will not change the amount of variation about the mean, but it can and does change the value of the standard deviation and mean.  Before the addition of the constant the mean and standard deviation were 3.024 and 3.298 respectively, after adding the constant the mean was increased to 7.024 and the standard deviation decreased to 2.977.

Comment: The standard deviation taken from the raw data remained exactly the same and showed an expected increase in the mean. However, the Most Likely Estimates (MLE) of the parameters  based on the assumption that the data follows the gamma distribution, increase.

Comment: These parameters are eventually plugged into equations that eventually result in long term averages and other water quality estimates.  Noticing the difference in the MLEs (of the original and data base with added constant) for the mean and standard deviation caused concern in that it may effect the magnitude of the water quality end values. It may be that the differences are inconsequential.  The only way to determine this (for me that is) is to do a couple of comparative calculations. Thank you for your input. It reminds me of how important definitions are in statistics.

Comment: @Marc The question is misleading about the situation. Your real question is about the effect of shifting on *maximumum likelihood estimates of standard deviation* under particular distrbutional assumptions.. You didn't mention maximum likelihood estimation at all. It would probably be best at this point to post a new question that gives the details you just explained in comments (and we'll probably ask for some additional information). We can then try to clarify the question a bit further, but it looks answerable -- it relates to whether or not the parametric family is a location-scale family.

Comment: ctd ... However, there are some issues with the underlying methodology that you describe which (hopefully) should also be raised in answers.